# Algorithms for finding coincidences in sets of data

Tags: algorithm, math, physics

**Background & Motivation**

I have three lists of timestamps (UNIX timestamps, plus a `10`-digit subsecond part (e.g. `1451606400.9475839201`)). They are *not* necessarily of the same size, however they *are* ordered (in non-descending order).

Each list corresponds to data from a real-life instrument, of which there are `3`. The instruments in question record a timestamp each time they observe an "event". The issue is that the instruments are *very* sensitive, thus they record timestamps on the order of `10+ hz`, and I'm working with a `~1 year` of data, where only a *tiny* portion correspond to actual events.

Unfortunately, it's difficult to put a number on precisely *how* many timestamps should be real events.

We may assume that the "random" timestamps are uniformly distributed (and, in practice, this seems to be the case). There are, however, gaps in the data (e.g. all three instruments may have gone down during the months of March, April, May). These gaps will be the same for all three lists.

Unfortunately, we cannot assume that the clocks for the three instruments are well synchronized. A drift of a fraction of a microsecond to a few microseconds can be expected. Further, the "events" in question are light, and the instruments in question close together, so we can calculate the maximum difference in observation time, on the order of `~10 - 15 microseconds` (assuming the clocks *were* synchronized, and there is no noise).

**Goal:**

Using *only* the timestamps, I want to identify those which are most "likely" to correspond to a "real" event, such that further analysis can be conducted.

**What I've Tried:**

My first inclination was to, from the three list, produce a list of triplets, one timestamp contributed by each list/instrument, such that `max(A,B,C) - min(A,B,C)` was minimized. Something like [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/smallest-difference-triplet-from-three-arrays/) simple algorithm.

Unfortunately, this found very few, and sometimes no, "coincidences" which fell within a reasonable time window. Further, those few that did didn't correspond to real events, upon further analysis.

---

Next, I tried the above, but this time minimizing the RSS error, which I defined to be, for some triplet `A,B,C`, as `(A-B)**2 + (A-C)**2 + (B-C)**2`. This found not too many more triplets within a reasonable time window, and none corresponded to real events.

---

Lastly, I tried simply iterating over all elements of the first vector, and finding the closest match in the second and third vectors (by binary search), then repeating for the second and third vectors. This gave me identical results to the RSS minimization code.

---

**Is there a better or a "standard" approach?**

I'm worried about nothing outside of effectively finding these "real events". This includes efficiency... if it works well, speed/efficiency is of little concern.

Comment: Have you tried a three pointer approach?

Comment: @AbhinavMathur Thanks for the suggestion! I'm not familiar with the "three pointer approach". How is this done?

Comment: without actually see the data (ideally also its plot) and showing event and the "random" parts we can only guess as we do not have enough info about the properties of the two signals ... So I can only recommend [correlation coefficient](http://mathbits.com/MathBits/TISection/Statistics2/correlation.htm) on sliding window of data from mine perspective as any better detector requires more info and sample data.

Comment: By my calculation, you should have about 21 triplets (within 15 µS of each other) that appear by chance. Do the known real events produce triplets like that? How many real events do you expect?